# Shifting values on a graph

Tags: calculus

I have been given the following information regarding shifting of plot points;

[image]

I am confused how a - can shift to the right and a + shifts to the left.

Here is a picture of the associated questions;

[image]

I am just going to use $a$ as the example (the answer provided is meant to be curve 3).

$$f(x - 4)$$

Let's make x = 7

$$f(7-4) = 3$$

But the graph has 7 = 0. If I use the information provided for shifting, I can see that 7 shifted to 3. Which went LEFT. If we take anything away from a starting x value, are we not moving left towards the negative values?

Comment: I don't understand what you don't understand.  If we look at the original graph of $f(x)$ and we wanted to use that and draw $g(x)=f(x-4)$, we can take the original blue graph of $f(x)$ on our piece of paper... cut it out with scissors (*leaving the axes where they are*)... and physically move it four units to the right... and the result is the graph of $g$.  Perhaps you are thinking about how we can take the graph of $g$ and move **g** four units to the left to get $f$... that isn't what we are talking about.  We are talking about how to move **f** to get $g$.

Comment: The blue curve is the one that is moving. In the example you gave, it moves to the right to where the curve 3 is.

Comment: @JMoravitz, your last sentence was exactly what I was missing. thank you so much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we make $x=7$ in $f(x-4)$ we get $f(3)$, not $3$.  Looking at the original graph, $f(3)=0$, so $f(x=4)=0 \text { when } x=7$

The reason $f(x-4)$ is $f(x)$ shifted $4$ units to the right is that $x-4$ is $x$ shifted four units to the left.  If I give you $x$, you look four units to the left, evaluate $f(x-4)$ and plot it at $x$, so you are plotting it right of the original curve.

Comment: That's perfect. Thank you so much! Can I please ask though, it's not really shifting to the right, is it? It's really, "Where did we shift from"?